# Angular: How to implement mat sorting in mat table with formarray

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material-table

I'm working on formArray in mat-table and the table can be sort. I just want a simple sorting based on id. Everything working good except sort. Please let me know where I made mistake here. Here is my code:
[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-with-form-pd48uf?file=app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

It's obvious that you got confused with the **Angular Material** table examples.

If you take a look on `MatTable` [example](https://run.stackblitz.com/api/angular/v1?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-sorting-example.ts) with `SortHeader` you will notice that you can add your `Sort` child to your `dataSource` only if your `dataSource` is an instance of `MatTableDataSource`.

like:
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);

```
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}
```

This doesn't work in your case, since your `albums` which's your `dataSource` is a `formArray`, so you can solve it by using the `matSortChange` event that calls your custom method of sorting.

HTML:

```
<mat-table
    matSort
    [dataSource]="albums.controls"
    (matSortChange)="sortAlbums($event)">
        <!-- your columns here -->
</mat-table>
```

Typescript:

```
sortAlbums(sort: Sort) {
    var list: Album[] = this.albums.value;
    switch (sort.direction) {
      case 'desc':
        list = list.sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id);
        break;
      default:
        list = list.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
        break;
    }
    this.albums.patchValue(list);
}
```